# SQLite LEFT JOIN ignored by WHERE clause

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, left-join, where-clause

I've got an SQLite database with 3 tables, `interests`, `events`, `categories`. You can add a category to your interests, and I need to write a query that pulls all events that are attached to that category.

You can also add an event to your interests, or disable an event so it doesn't show up beneath a category.

e.g. interested in all "Big Bang Theory" episodes, but disable the a single episode that you've already seen.

This query selects all events for a category in the interests table, including the disabled events:

```
SELECT events.id AS event_id, events.title, event_interests.disabled
FROM interests
    JOIN events ON events.category_id = interests.id 
        AND interests.type LIKE "category" 
    LEFT JOIN interests AS event_interests ON event_interests.id = events.id 
        AND event_interests.type LIKE "event"
```

Which gives these results:

```
Event_ID  Title          Disabled   
122749    Bad Education    
122815    Bad Education  1
122852    Bad Education
```

This query does exactly the same thing but limits to disabled interests

```
SELECT events.id AS event_id, events.title, event_interests.disabled
FROM interests
    JOIN events ON events.category_id = interests.id 
        AND interests.type LIKE "category" 
    LEFT JOIN interests AS event_interests ON event_interests.id = events.id 
        AND event_interests.type LIKE "event" 
WHERE event_interests.disabled = 1
```

Only the disabled row is returned

```
Event_ID  Title          Disabled    
122815    Bad Education  1
```

But I want to get all events **that are not** disabled. But inverting the `WHERE event_interests.disabled` isn't giving me that:

```
SELECT events.id AS event_id, events.title, event_interests.disabled
FROM interests
    JOIN events ON events.category_id = interests.id 
        AND interests.type LIKE "category" 
    LEFT JOIN interests AS event_interests ON event_interests.id = events.id 
        AND event_interests.type LIKE "event" 
WHERE event_interests.disabled != 1
```

This gives a blank results set, instead of returning the events **122749, 122852**

Have I done something stupid with my JOINs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `disabled` column can be `NULL`.
To test against `NULL`, you always have to be specific: `WHERE disabled IS NULL`.

Basically, almost any comparison with `NULL` always results in `NULL`.
So if you ask "Give me all rows where disabled is not 1", the database is unable to give you rows with `NULL`, because for all it knows, that `NULL` might mean "No data, but could be 1".

More surprising information [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html).

Comment: It can be NULL, 1 or 0. I want to get the 0 or the NULLs

Comment: Then you have to say that explicitly: `disabled = 0 OR disabled IS NULL`.

Comment: Yes I can! `WHERE event_interests.disabled IS NULL OR event_interests.disabled = 0` works fine. Thanks Denis. Why is that though, seeing as `1 != NULL`

Comment: `1 != NULL` is false. `1 = NULL` is also false. Check out the article in the documentation that I've given a link to in my answer for more details.

Comment: Ah ok, good edit, thanks Denis. I should have thought of this, this kind of thing with NULL happens all over MySQL as well

Comment: Also I can't accept your answer for 6 minutes - but I will do

Comment: @Denis 1 != NULL is null, 1 = NULL is also null. Any arithmetic comparison to NULL is null (not false) - a good way to memorize this is to think that NULL means "unknown" i.e. in fact NULL represents some existing value which we compare some other value to - they can be the same, they can be different but since we don't know it, the result of such comparison is null (=unknown).

Comment: @miazo Of course, you're right. I knew that, I just meant that in the context of author's `WHERE` filter the result is _falsy_. Thanks for clearing it up.